# Ansible difference filter not reading 2 parameters from host_vars with the same name

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to check the difference between a specific config I'm getting from an host and what I have on the `host_vars` file and then save the differences which will be used to do new configurations.

My host_vars is like this:

```yaml
---
config1:
 - name: "test"
   var1: "x"
   var1: "y"
```

The difference is done correctly and checks that this one is the only one missing but apparently is only saving the `"var1": "y"` and not the `"var1 : "x"`.

```
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "list_of_new_configs": [
                {
                    "var1": "y",
                    "name": "test"
                }
            ]
        },
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}
```

This is how I'm saving the new list:

```yaml
- name: Create default list of new configs
  set_fact:
    list_of_new_configs: "{{ config1 | difference(running_conf_configs) | list }}"
```

Is there a way to save both `var1` in this list or declare them in a way they are both accepted?
They are parameters on the host config and need to have the same name.

Comment: Because a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) cannot have two keys being the same. If you want to diff them, either create two different items on your list or create two dictionaries (e.g. `config1` and `config2`)

Comment: Hi, i manage to do it by listing them under the same name : 
- name: "test"
   var1: 
     "x"
     "y"